# For composite functions, how can I prove that the limit of a function exists if and only if its composite's limit also exists.

Tags: real-analysis

If I were to have a function $f$ such that its domain is $[1,\infty]$ and another function $g$ which has domain $(0,1]$ and is defined to be $g(x) = f(1/x)$, how can I prove using the definition of limits that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{g(x)}$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{f(x)}$ exists as well?

My idea is like the suggestion to first, use the definition of limits. So proving the first direction, assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{g(x)}$ exists. Then, let $g$ be a function such that $g:(0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $0$ be a cluster point of $(0,1] \cap (0,\infty)$. Thus, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1], 0 < x < 0+\delta, |g(x)-L| < \epsilon$. Next, because $g(x) = f(1/x), f: [1,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

But I get stuck around here as I do not know how to then relate the above statement to show the definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{f(x)}$. I believe I would run into the same issue when proving the converse as well.

Comment: You have quoted the limit definition correctly.  Now you claim that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$, which means that if I give you $\epsilon'$ you can find $M$ so that $x \gt M \implies |f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon'$.  So I give you $\epsilon'$.  You need to go to the person who told you about the limit of $g(x)$, give them an $\epsilon$ (which is based on my $\epsilon'$), take the $\delta$ they give you, and find an $M$ to give back to me.

Comment: I may be thinking it too simply, but can I just say $M = 1/ \epsilon$? I know this is the case if you compare two separate functions but $g(x)$ essentially depends on $f(1/x)$. Would the benefit of this be the fact that they can use the same $x$ rather than having to do $x,y$ or something? I think I am slowly starting to see the direction that this is going but still fail to actually go through with it.

Comment: You need to produce $\epsilon$, then ask for $\delta$ in the limit definition of $g(x)$.  That $\delta$ is what you use to find $M$.  The point is that $g(x)$ could have an enormous slope near $x=0$, which makes $\delta$ very small.  That means $f(1/x)$ is far from $L$ until $M$ is very large.  In fact, $M$ will be $1/\delta$